# Count number of lego bricks needed to build a house

Tags: java

I am trying to calculate how many lego bricks i need to build a simple lego house.

I have the following bricks: 1x2, 2x2, 2x4.

I need to calculate how many of which brick i need to build the lego house by a given width, length and height.

The width and length is givin in dots as seen on a lego plate.
the height is given as a lego bricks heigth.

e.g: a 2x4 lego brick is ((2*4)*2).
like this: [image]

e.g: If i want to build a house that is:
    8 dots wide | 7 dots long | 1 block tall

The output should tell me i need:

- Total Dots: 56
- 1x2: 2 bricks
- 2x2: 2 bricks
- 2x4: 4 bricks

So that if i were to build the lego house with the given bricks it would look like this: [image]

So far my code show me how many of each brick i can use to build the house, but i cant figure out how to make it show only the absolute necessary bricks needed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;

    int oneXtwo = (1 * 2);
    int twoXtwo = (2 * 2);
    int twoXfour = (2 * 4);

    System.out.println(oneXtwo + "\t" + twoXtwo + "\t" + twoXfour + "\n");

    int totalDots;
    int oneXtwoTotal;
    int twoXtwoTotal;
    int twoXfourTotal;

    System.out.print("Length: ");
    length = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Width: ");
    width = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Height: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();

    totalDots = (length * width) * height;
    oneXtwoTotal = (((length * width) / oneXtwo) * (height));
    twoXtwoTotal = (((length * width) / twoXtwo) * (height));
    twoXfourTotal = (((length * width) / twoXfour) * (height));

    System.out.println("Total Dots: " + totalDots);
    System.out.println("Total 1x2: " + oneXtwoTotal);
    System.out.println("Total 2x2: " + twoXtwoTotal);
    System.out.println("Total 2x4: " + twoXfourTotal);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be fairly easy. You start with the first side and divide by the length of the largest block you have, rounded down. This is the number of these blocks you need. Then you take do `[length] modulo [length of longest block]` to get the remaining dots you need. Now you repeat the process with the next block size until you did it with all blocks.

Now you take the second side, subtract four dots and then perform the same algorithm.

Of course you need to handle the special case of a house with width and/or height lower than 4 separately.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that.

Comment: So, i have now calculated how many dots the total area needed is, but i can't figure out how to "divide" it into sides so that i can calculate how many of the bricks i need.

Comment: I declare these variables  

`int width = 8;`  
`int length = 7`  
`int thiccness = 2` (a lego brick is 2 thick)

Comment: Then i use this to calculate the area: `int totalArea = (width*length) - ((width-(2*thiccness)) * (length - (2*thiccness)));`